# Distance to nearest null node to the left (Parallel algorithm)

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

Let's say I have an array list of objects `objects`.
Could anyone suggest a parallel algorithm to find the distance to the nearest null object to the left of any `objects[i]`?

I know how to this sequentially, which takes `O(n)`, but I need a faster one which can be done in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have `k` threads available.

> 1. Divide the array to k parts, each of size n/k.
> 2. In each thread, you have a subarray with n/k elements.
>      
>     2.1. Set a variable `lastNull` - holding the index of the last null in this chunk
> 3. barrier - all threads must end before reaching here
> 4. the "master" thread now iterates the values of the k threads, and sends the index of the closest null (to the left) to each chunk
> 5. all threads iterate their data and set the correct value for each.

Complexity:

- Step 1 takes O(k) time - sending data to `k` threads. (assuming shared memory model, otherwise you are going to need to send the data which will take O(n), no way around it)
- Step 2 takes O(n/k) time for each thread and is done in parallel
- Step 3 is a simple barrier, and is O(k) - waiting for all threads.
- Step 4 is O(k) - polling data from each thread, and then iterating and pushing data to each thread.
- Step 5 is O(n/k) again for each thread and is done in parallel.

Small note: Theoretically, one can usually optimize the O(k) phases to also do them in parallel, but that is usually redundant unless dealing with huge clusters of thousands of machines.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I think I saw a small hole in your algorithm.
Suppose I have an array with data looking like this: (where x is non-null obj) and have 4 threads:
    `X|X|null|X| X|X|X|X| X|null|X|X| X|X|null|X`
Then Step 2: thread 1 has `lastNull = 2`, thread 2 has `lastNull = 0`, thread 3 has `lastNull=1` and thread 3 has `lastNull = 2`.
Now step 3: thread 2 is fine, it gets 2 from the master. But for thread 3, it also gets 0 while it SHOULD get 5 since the closest null to its left is 5 elements away.

Comment: @abcXYZ no, thread1 has `lastNull=2`, thread2 has `lastNull=NaN` (Not a Number, and is ignored by the master for this purpose), thread 3 has `lastNull= 9`, thread 4 has `lastNull=14`. (Recall that each thread can "know" which indices he's performing on, because he got it from the master in step 1). So, you send to thread2 `2`, to thread3 `2`, to thread 4 `10`, and from there it's easy to calculate. Hope it helps, and good night.